# Vertically align two lines of text inside a div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Before this post I read couple of articles on the topic and I'm already aware of some of the used tricks for vertical align - the line-height for single line of text, the display:table for couple of divs and Flexbox in CSS3. But I still need help to align two lines inside a div:

```css
.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 70vh;
}

.key {
  border: 0.1rem solid white;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

kbd {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="keys">
  <div class="key" data-key="65"><kbd>A</kbd><span class="sound">text</span></div>
  <div class="key" data-key="83"><kbd>S</kbd><span class="sound">text</span></div>
  <div class="key" data-key="68"><kbd>D</kbd><span class="sound">text</span></div>
  <div class="key" data-key="70"><kbd>F</kbd><span class="sound">text</span></div>
</div>
```

As you can see I already have a flexbox container and to use display:table will need an extra div. Maybe playing with the padding or some relative positioning would be the answer. What's the best way to vertically center this text content?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle? I'm also not sure what you mean by vert *align* two lines inside a div.

Comment: you should set your border and text to black, otherwise it is hard to see your example.

Answer (score 2):

Changed answer after comment:

Add this to `.key` to also make it a flex container which centers its contents above each other (the already existing `text-align: center` does the horizontal text-centering):

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

(Note: Since everything is white and therefore remains invisible, I added a black background to the `.key` elements)

```css
.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 70vh;
}

.key {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0.1rem solid white;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

kbd {
}
```

```html
<div class="keys">
  <div class="key" data-key="65"><kbd>A</kbd><span class="sound">text</span></div>
  <div class="key" data-key="83"><kbd>S</kbd><span class="sound">text</span></div>
  <div class="key" data-key="68"><kbd>D</kbd><span class="sound">text</span></div>
  <div class="key" data-key="70"><kbd>F</kbd><span class="sound">text</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I didn't manage to explain well what I'd like to achieve, sorry about that. What I need is the word "text" to be positioned below the letter and both lines to be centered vertically and horizontally. How to do that ?

Comment: Ah okay - please note my changed answer

Comment: thank you! so the child elements of a flexbox can also be displayed as flexbox ?? That's cool ! What about the properties applied to the child elements like flex-grow, flex-shrink etc.. they will still have effect or not ?

Comment: yes, you can make any flex-child a flex-container, with all the usual rules applying

Comment: holy moly it took a while to find an answer that worked for me haha. thanks!